# SQL SELECT from based on truth table

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I select the columns to be returned by a lookup truth table?
my data:

```
| nam | X | Y |
| Bob | 2 | 5 |
| Jan | 1 | 6 |
```

the lookup table

```
| prop| SHOW |
| nam | true |
|  X  | false|
|  Y  | true |
```

someting like `SELECT from data (columns which have "true" in lookup)` resulting in:

```
| nam | Y |
| Bob | 5 |
| Jan | 6 |
```

Comment: Could you provide more information? The structure of this tables are a little bit strange for be a relational database like MySQL. Thanks you!

Comment: The little tables are just for Illustration of the problem how to filter columns to be returned using a lookup table. The actual tables are much wider/longer.

Comment: @Fred . . . This requires dynamic SQL.  I would advise you to use views instead of a lookup table to control the columns that are visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a pivot table

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE tab1 (
  `nam` VARCHAR(3),
  `X` INTEGER,
  `Y` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO tab1
  (`nam`, `X`, `Y`)
VALUES
  ('Bob', '2', '5'),
  ('Jan', '1', '6');

CREATE TABLE tab2 (
  `prop` VARCHAR(3),
  `SHOW` VARCHAR(5)
);

INSERT INTO tab2
  (`prop`, `SHOW`)
VALUES
  ('nam', 'true'),
  ('X', 'false'),
  ('Y', 'true');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT CONCAT ('SELECT ',GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('`',prop,'`')),' FROM tab1;') 
       INTO @sql 
FROM tab2 WHERE `SHOW` = 'true';
```

There are no results to be displayed.

---

**Query #2**

```
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
```

There are no results to be displayed.

---

**Query #3**

```
EXECUTE stmt;

| nam | Y   |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | 5   |
| Jan | 6   |
```

---

There are no results to be displayed.

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iGg1g98L9JUioCiDP28bEf/19)

Comment: This is great. Thanks! As a SQL beginner I wouldn't come close to this.